# How to store month, day, and year in a variable in Google Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

How would I store "yy," "dd," and "MM," in a var?

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(unformattedDate, "EST", "MM/dd/yy");
```

Comment: Perhaps you might want to store them in [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want the formatted values of "yy", "dd", and "MM", so you should look at using [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(unformattedDate, "EST", "MM/dd/yy");
var dateParts = date.split("/"); // [MM, dd, yy]
var month = dateParts[0];
var day = dateParts[1];
var year = dateParts[2];
```